# PouchDB: Create a design doc for fetching unique keys

Tags: javascript, couchdb, pouchdb

Every doc in my database has a `tags` property which consists of an array of strings. Different docs can contain the same tags.

For example:

```
docA: {
  _id: "1234567",
  tags: ["foo", "bar"]
},
var docB: {
  _id: "9876543",
  tags: ["bar", "baz"]
}
```

I need to create a design doc to retrieve all unique tags. If the design doc ran for the example shown above, it would return: `["foo", "bar", "baz"]`.

I am not entirely sure how to go about doing so. Should I be doing it in `pouchdb` or `couchdb` ? Would I need a reduce function?

Comment: if you wanted to use reduce, concat() would work (after you collect the tags)

Comment: That is, create a design doc and use it to collect tags and then use concat? I was hoping there is a built in pouchdb method of doing so right in the design document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is exactly what you want: 
http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/cookbook.html#unique